# How can i submit an Imagefile using ajax in django

Tags: javascript, django

I have  my jquery and ajax as follows . IT works pretty good in submitting normal data but not imagefiles.
What i my suppose to do to rectify this problem and make it work to submit image files of my django model form .

```
$('#my-form').submit(function(e)){
 e.preventDefault();
 var formaurl=$(this).attr("data-url")||window.locate.href;
 var formdata=$(this).serialize();
 $.ajax({
 url:formurl,
 type:'POST',
 data:formdata,
 success:SuccessFunction,
 error:ErrorFuntion,

 django model form 

 class Post(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
        field=('image1','image2','productname','productdetail')
```

productname and productdetail is submited successfully to the data base except  image1 and image2 . Please help me . I have search the internet but yet i can not find a solution .

Answer (score 0):

Access file through request.Files

eg:
  file = forms.FileField()

[From django dcumentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/)